# What is being passed as first parameter of a new Intent instance?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I'm talking about that line of code above. Which I wrote in my MainActivity class under the onCreate method. It is supposed to activate the second activity. But I want to understand what is that "this" in the parameter?

Comment: from the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29

Comment: Intent first param take Context class instance and in your case if MainActivity extending Activity then we can also pass `this` refers to a reference of the current class. because MainActivity class extending Activity and Activity is subclass of Context class. so we are able to pass `this` as first param to Intent constructor

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to read the documentation associated with this call :

**@param packageContext A Context of the application package implementing
 this class.
 @param cls The component class that is to be used for the intent.**

So the first parameter is simply a `context`

If you try to dig deeper, you'll see that this context is used to create a `ComponentName`, which says

A Context for the package implementing the component, from which the actual package name will be retrieved.

Comment: Which means if I will be using it inside a Fragment class it should be written as

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: Or simply `Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);`